# Selecting the color of bars from a variable

Tags: r, plotly

I want to set some previously selected colors to my barplot. For example, I want Ferrari to be red, Mercedes turquoise...

You can use, for example, the following simple dataset:

```
structure(list(points = c(3183, 27, 210, 334, 352, 898, 559, 812, 3796, 2508), name = c("Ferrari", 
"Williams", "Aston Martin", "Haas F1 Team", "AlphaTauri", "McLaren", 
"Alfa Romeo", "Alpine F1 Team", "Red Bull", "Mercedes"), color = c("red", "lightblue", "darkgreen", "darkred", "black", "grey", "darkblue", "pink", "yellow", "turquoise")), row.names = 1:9, class = "data.frame")
```

I tried to use the following code:

```
library(plotly)
library(dplyr)
plot_ly(data, x =~name, y=~points, color = ~name, colors = ~color)%>%add_bars()
```

And I had the following result (the colors are not what I wanted):

[image: plotly example]

Answer (score 1):

Your `name` variable is being coerced to a factor and ordered alphabetically. Make it a factor and will correspond with the color order you defined.

`df$name <- factor(df$name, levels = unique(df$name))`

[image]

Answer (score 1):

A second option would be to use a named vector of colors which assigns colors to names. This way the right colors are assigned independent of the order of the `name` column:

```r
pal_color <- setNames(data$color, data$name)
pal_color
#>        Ferrari       Williams   Aston Martin   Haas F1 Team     AlphaTauri 
#>          "red"    "lightblue"    "darkgreen"      "darkred"        "black" 
#>        McLaren     Alfa Romeo Alpine F1 Team       Red Bull       Mercedes 
#>         "grey"     "darkblue"         "pink"       "yellow"    "turquoise"

library(plotly)

plot_ly(data, x = ~name, y = ~points, color = ~name, colors = pal_color) %>% 
  add_bars()
```

[image]